# disable users from creating new shell instances

Tags: linux, shell, sudoers

Is there any way I can disable users from creating new shell instances through sudoers file? also disable them to set any environment variables?

I would like to write a line in the sudoers file something like:

`someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL, NOTSETENVVARS: ALL, NONEWSHELLINSTANCES: ALL`

where:
NOTSETENVVARS means the instruction to no set new env vars
NONEWSHELLINSTANCES means no new shell instances

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd not try to combine this with `ALL`. If you're trying to restrict a user, blacklist them first then whitelist carefully.

Restrict shell escapes with `NOEXEC:`
Check the man page for details: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.16/sudoers.man.html#Preventing_shell_escapes

Restrict environment variables (not fully disable to my knowledge) with creative use of `env_reset` and `secure_path`.

Example:

```
Defaults     env_reset
Defaults     secure_path
someuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SOMESPECIFICCOMMANDS
someuser ALL=(root) NOEXEC: /usr/bin/vim
```

Also, buy Michael W. Lucas's book **Sudo Mastery**. It is great! (He has some better examples, but I thought it better not to plagiarize them.)

Answer (score 0):

No.

Controls like this do not exist because they can be trivially circumvented by the user installing / executing their own shell program without the restrictions or with the restrictions patched out.

There is no way to know if a program is a shell or not.

Moreover, the `sudoers` file only controls the utility `sudo`, not anything the user executes before running `sudo`, or after they have elevated.